# rvmのRubyのバージョンとbundlerで指定したディレクトリ配下のバージョンがあっていない

Tags: ruby, rubygems

### rvmの設定とvendorディレクトリ配下の様子

```
% ruby -v
ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-darwin14]
```

---

```
% cat .ruby-version 
2.2.3
```

---

```
% ls vendor/bundle/ruby/      
2.2.0
```

### 説明

上記のようにbundlerはパスを指定してインストールしております。
rvmのバージョンが`2.2.3`にもかかわらず、bundlerで指定したパスの`ruby`ディレクトリの番号は`2.2.0`です。プロジェクト全体の動作自体は問題なく動いております。

なぜ番号が違うのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vendor/bundle/ruby/の方の2.2.0はABI(Application Binary Interface)のバージョンです。Ruby 2.2.xの間はABIバージョンは2.2.0になります

[Ruby 2.1.0 以降のセマンティックバージョニングについて](https://www.ruby-lang.org/ja/news/2013/12/21/ruby-version-policy-changes-with-2-1-0/)

Answer (score 1):

vendor/bundle/ruby の下のバージョンは、Ruby の API バージョンです。

Ruby のバージョン 2.2.3 の末尾の 3 はパッチレベルで、この番号が増加しても API には変更ないため、API バージョンは 2.2.0 のままです。